# Why my Angular 5 Parent form not seeing the Child form event

Tags: angular

This should have been a very straight forward exercise but its turning out to be a mystery. I have a parent for Home and a child form SearchForm. I am using ngForm to collect a two property object (city and dates) in the searchForm and pass this info to the parent form. The data is collected and the emit function is executed when the submit button is clicked....so an event should have been emitted...a console.log of the collected data shows that the data was passed.   However the very next which is the emit code was either not executed or the parent is not seeing the event. I get no errors anywhere but the console.log line in searchCriteria() of homeComponent.ts is not executed.....can anyone explain whats going on here? The code is below:

**homeComponent.html**

```
 <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
   <h2>TITLE</h2>
   <p>Text Text</p>
   <app-search-form>(searchEvent)='searchCriteria($event)'</app-search-form>

 </div>
................
```

**homeComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, OnDestroy, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
..
..
import {SearchFormComponent} from '../search-form/search-form.component';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedCriteria: {};
  cities: Observable<City[]>;

    constructor(private apollo: Apollo) { }

    ngOnInit() {
     ..
    }
    public searchCriteria(data) {
      this.selectedCriteria = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log('selected Criteria: ' + this.selectedCriteria );

    }

}
```

**searchForm.html**

```
    <form #searchForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSearchSubmit(searchForm)">
        <div class="row">
            ..........
        </div>
        <!-- collects data and send to home via onSearchSubmit() -->

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**searchForm.ts**

```
   import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-search-form',
      templateUrl: './search-form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./search-form.component.scss']
    })
    export class SearchFormComponent implements OnInit {
      @Output() searchEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

      searchResults = {
        selectedCity: '',
        travelDates: ''
      };
      selectedCities:  string[] = [
        'New York',
        'Miami',
        ......
       ];      // SelectedCities;

constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
      onSearchSubmit(searchForm: NgForm) {

    this.searchResults.selectedCity = searchForm.value.selectedCity;
    this.searchResults.travelDates = searchForm.value.selectedCity;
    console.log('Search Results:  ' + JSON.stringify(this.searchResults));
    this.searchEvent.emit(JSON.stringify(this.searchResults)); 
    searchForm.resetForm();
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo mistake , try this

```
   <app-search-form (searchEvent)='searchCriteria($event)'></app-search-form>
```

Comment: Damm...you have an eagle eye...I looked this for hours..even checked all the spellings...THANKS